# Unwanted underscores appear in textbox in Windows CE application

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I have created a windows CE application. It downloads some data and presents them on a windows form.

I have seen that sometimes ghostly underscore (`_`) is seen in textbox  although there is no `_` in data which is downloaded.

I have already trimmed data also wrote code to remove `_` from data if at all it is there. Still the `_` is seen in text box.

Please help

Comment: This is an underscore: > _ < . Do you mean quotation marks? > " <. Please also give a sample of the unwanted data and the code where you modify the downloaded data, only then can we help with identifying the issue

Comment: I mean underscore > _ <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created windows CE windows forms application with compact framework 3.5.
When I set "&" static data in textbox value it shows me "_"
When I set "&&" in textbox value it shows me "&".

So this was the issue. 
So I replaced "&" with "&&" in the data which I receive before setting it to textbox.

This has solved my issue.

Comment: It sounds like you're using something other than a normal textbox - maybe a label control? `&` is used to mark the accelerator (shortcut) key for controls, but there shouldn't be any special processing for these within the body of a textbox control.